# Get powershell variable values from WMI Invokemethod

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

I am working on a c# service that is calling powershell using invokemethod (I used this route due to the requirements and need to use .net 2). So my question is, if I set values in this WMI invoke, can I pull them back into the original thread? An example would be something like (pseudocode):

wmi.invokemethod("powershell.exe -command &(invoke-command {$a=(get-acl).path;return $path}));

In the case above I would like to grab the $path variable but haven't found any articles with a way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Joe

Comment: Does that actually work? Calling an arbitrary command as the only argument to `InvokeMethod()`?

Comment: The complete syntax was (process class, and the powershell commmands (inparams["commandline") were assigned earlier):
ManagmentBaseObject outparams=processclass.InvokeMethod("Create",inparams,null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of info on the web about executing PS scripts from C# and retrieving whatever (pipeline) output the PS script creates. Here is a blog that describes the process: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx . Here is the actual API documented: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449(v=vs.85).aspx . Note that page has an example as well.

If you are going to be executing a user's script and need to retrieve a variable that it sets (versus a script you write yourself), then you can write a wrapper script that dot sources the user script and then after the user's script completes your wrapper script outputs $path (or whatever other variable you like) to the pipeline, where your C# code will be able to retrieve it.

BTW, I don't think there's any simple way to do what it sounds like you're describing via WMI Invoke. The method described above will work on .Net 2.0.

One thing you might think of to do, to achieve this is for the process created by wmi.invoke to alter it's parent's (your C# service) environment. However as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009(v=vs.85).aspx that's not possible (see the Community comments at the bottom of the page for more depth).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Ill check into the articles you mentioned.